# How to prevent "out of memory" error while uploading files with access-VBA?

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, upload, out-of-memory

I loop through a folder and try to upload every file in the folder into an document management system with the following code:

```
Dim webRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set webRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Call webRequest.Open(HTTPPost, adress, False)

Const Boundary As String = "AaB03x"
Call webRequest.setRequestHeader(HTTPHeaderValueContentType, "multipart/form-data;boundary=" & Boundary)
Call webRequest.setRequestHeader(HTTPHeaderValueCallingApplication, get_sys_db)
Call webRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
Call webRequest.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")

Dim byteData As Variant
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = StreamType.Binary
    .Mode = StreamMode.ReadWrite
    .Open
    Call .LoadFromFile(fileName)
    byteData = .Read  'Somethimes here I get the "out of memory" error
End With

'dim requestData as Variant
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Mode = StreamMode.ReadWrite
    .Charset = WindowsCharset
    .Open
    .Type = StreamType.Text
    Dim uploadFilename As String
    uploadFilename = ZConverter.VariantToString(cut_file(fileName))
    .WriteText CreateContentDisposionText("itemName", uploadFilename, Boundary)  
    .WriteText CreateContentDisposionText("parentNickname", parentNickname, Boundary) 
    .WriteText vbNewLine & "--" & Boundary & vbNewLine & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbNewLine 
    .WriteText vbNewLine
    .Position = StreamPositionStart
    .Type = StreamType.Binary
    .Position = .Size
    .Write byteData
    Set byteData = Nothing
    .Position = StreamPositionStart
    .Type = StreamType.Text
    .Position = .Size
    .WriteText vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "--" & Boundary & "--" & vbNewLine
    .Position = StreamPositionStart
    .Type = StreamType.Binary
    Call webRequest.Send(.Read) 'Here I get the "out of memory" error most of the time
End With
```

So this works fine for small files.

But when I try to upload a file with 420 mb I get the error: "Not enough memory available for this task" (original: "Für diesen Vorgang ist nicht genügend Speicher verfügbar."). With the VBE (The development enviroment) open it fails even with 20 mb-files.

Access needs ~ 55 mb ram with closed VBE and 140 mb with a open VBE. As the memory usage always falls back to this values I dont think there is a memory leak.

So: Is there a way to extend the ram available to access as there is > 3GB free ram on the computer?
And if not, is there a way to change the code so that there is not as much memory needed at once?

Update:
How I upload the file is the result of this question of mine on stack overflow: [Upload pdf via multipart-HTML-Post does change file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389091/upload-pdf-via-multipart-html-post-does-change-file)

Comment: You could try closing your streams each time, maybe use the actual libraries also, so no create objects, not 100%

Comment: @Nathan_Sav:  I added a .Close before every "end with" but I could not see any changes.

Comment: I don't understand why you're reading the stream data into a byte array, then writing that byte array to a stream, then reading that stream back into a byte array and then sending it. Afaik this causes the entire file to be in memory at least 4 times, while it should be in memory at most twice. Ideally, however, you'd use a chunking upload (so that only a few KB needs to be in memory at once), but that's a pretty advanced subject.

Comment: @Erik A: I dont think the file is in memory 4 times at once. I load it into the byteArray. Then I load it into the other stream and delete the fist stream. Then I load it into the webRequest. But of course Im open for any other way to do this. How I upload the file is the result of this question of mine on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389091/upload-pdf-via-multipart-html-post-does-change-file

Comment: I'd need to know exactly what the website expects. Combining form data with chunked binary data in a single request is not something I've ever done, so I don't know if it's possible. If you're not using chunking, the entire file needs to be in memory, and that severely limits the possibility of uploading large files. Usually, APIs that expect large files have a way to send the form data in a header, the request URI, or something else entirely.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: rubberduck is loaded but not not refreshed. But as explained in the question the problem also exists with the closed VBE.

Comment: @Erik A: I dont have any information about any other possibilities the APIs gives. But Ill ask the colleges which are resonsible for that system (its an openText-System)

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: And its 32-bit access...

Comment: IIRC 32-bit host are limited to 2GB, regardless of available RAM. Not that 2GB shouldn't be more than enough though

Comment: I get the error with ~ 550mb. So there seems to be a lot room for data...

Comment: Maybe this https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/32586994-make-32-bit-access-large-address-aware-laa might be helping to solve the issue.